# Correct DNS records?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I just got a VPS (2 CPU, 2 Gb RAM, 40 GB SSD).

I've downloaded and configured Virtualmin/Webmin.

I have two domain names nedegroup.com and nutrizzio.com registered through godaddy.

With nedegroup.com I created my nameservers ns1.nedegroup.com and ns2.nedegroup.com, both points to my VPS ip 188.226.139.41 , then I've added those name servers to nedegroup.com and nutrizzio.com nameservers.

I've added nedegroup.com to virtualmin and I have the following DNS record for it:

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ns1.nedegroup.com. root.ns1.nedegroup.com. (
            1391023495
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  ns1.nedegroup.com.
nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
www.nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
ftp.nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
m.nedegroup.com.    IN  A   188.226.139.41
localhost.nedegroup.com.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
admin.nedegroup.com.    IN  A   188.226.139.41
mail.nedegroup.com. IN  A   188.226.139.41
nedegroup.com.  IN  MX  0 mail.nedegroup.com.
nedegroup.com.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:nedegroup.com ip4:188.226.139.41 ?all"
ns2.nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
host.nedegroup.com. IN  A   188.226.139.41
nedegroup.com.  IN  NS  ns2.nedegroup.com.
autoconfig.nedegroup.com.   IN  A   188.226.139.41
ns1.nedegroup.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
```

And for nutrizzio.com I have the following records:

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ns1.nedegroup.com. root.ns1.nedegroup.com. (
            1391033575
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  ns1.nedegroup.com.
nutrizzio.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
ftp.nutrizzio.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
localhost.nutrizzio.com.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.nutrizzio.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
admin.nutrizzio.com.    IN  A   188.226.139.41
mail.nutrizzio.com. IN  A   188.226.139.41
nutrizzio.com.  IN  MX  5 mail.nutrizzio.com.
nutrizzio.com.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:nutrizzio.com ip4:188.226.139.41 ?all"
autoconfig.nutrizzio.com.   IN  A   188.226.139.41
nutrizzio.com.  IN  NS  ns2.nedegroup.com.
www.nutrizzio.com.  IN  A   188.226.139.41
```

I want to know if this is enough ? Or I have to do more configuration ?

Also I would like to know:

+++ why when I type webmail.nedegroup.com nothing happens. It says it cannot find the server in browser.
+++ I can receive emails from Yahoo, Hotmail , but I can't send email to these domains, where should I check for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to troubleshoot Dns use **DIG tool** .

Second you should make a reverse zone and piont IPSs to your hostnames .

Third you should state in your clients that in /etc/network/interfaces the dns they should use .

Hope it helps .

Comment: What is a reverse zone exactly? This might be a silly question but I am quite a newbie

Comment: check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto